# How to add multiplexer to my circuit to drive 7 segment display every 10 seconds from 2 different inputs alternately

Tags: multiplexer, 7segmentdisplay

I've been working on this project and got stuck at a problem in my schematic. I want to display the *temperature* and the *count* from the counters alternately every 10 seconds. In other words: display the count...10 seconds later display the temperature...10 seconds later display the count ad infinitum.[image]

I have an 8 bit temperature value and I want it to be displayed as well using the exact same LEDs. I could use a multiplexer with an oscillator but I have no Idea how I would hook it up to this circuit.
Here is a rough block diagram of what I'm trying to achieve overall:

[image]

Here is the remainder of the schematic I've been trying to tweek:

[image]

Comment: What sort of LED displays are these? Do they have decoding built-in from binary to 7 segment patterns?

Comment: I didn't put the decoder just to simplify things. But in the full solution, I will include the BCD to 7 segment drivers

Comment: Well, then just drive your displays from the outputs from a set of 2 to 1 multiplexers and connect the counter outputs to one set of inputs, the temperature value to the other set and drive the select line with an oscillator. Might be helpful to have some way of showing which value is currently being displayed.

Comment: ...though personally I'd do this with a PIC or similar MCU, it's much easier.

Comment: Yup. That's what I want to do.(Not with the microcontroller). I'm actually looking for an example schematic of how to accomplish this.

Comment: @ZiphoLunika, do you not know how to implement a 555 timer circuit or do you not know how to make a multiplexer? Which software tool did you use to make the schematic?

Comment: I know how to implement a 555 timer. Just wanted an example of how to implement a 2:1 mux. But I got it now.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple, you have a two digit counter, each digit outputs 4 bits, those 4 bits go to a decoder/driver/display. You have a temperature represented by two 4 bit digits that get sent to the same decoders/drivers/displays. For each digit you need four 2 to 1 multiplexers. The outputs of the counter go to one set of multiplexer inputs, the temperature goes to the other set of inputs, then you toggle the multiplexer select input high and low at 10 second intervals.

So for one digit it would look something like this. For the second digit you would just duplicate this, both digits would have their multiplexers switched by the same 10 second clock source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffB71N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, this is assuming your temperature values are BCD. If they're not, you need to have a way to convert them.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out using a 74hc157D 2:1 multiplexer, a 555 timer and a couple of 4 Bit BCD values. Although in this case, the 555 timer has a frequency of about 1hz and about 50% duty cycle. Sorry for the small schematic
[image]